# Are std::net::TcpStream write or flush blocking operations?

Tags: rust

In Rust, Is std::net::TcpStream write or flush a blocking operation?
and is flush required to write the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [documentation for write](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Write.html#tymethod.write):

> Calls to write are not guaranteed to block waiting for data to be written, and a write which would otherwise block can be indicated through an Err variant.

Comment: thanks, If I understood correctly it will never block since it will return an error if it does, what about flush, is it required for TcpStream and does it block.

Comment: flush is not required, but yes, it blocks unless there's an error.